# Experience with iphonejailbreakunlock.com

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, unlock

My sisters iPhone needs to get unlocked. A [previous topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43529/help-me-unlock-a-german-iphone-4-ios-5-1) didn't help me out, despite the great answers and suggestions. So a colleague of me advised I should buy the 
[iphonejailbreakunlock.com](http://www.iphonejailbreakunlock.com).
It's a $27,99 software bundle which claims to be able to unlock any baseband on any device on any cellular network with a 100% money back guarantee... If you ask me, it's a bit to good to be true.

So, is there anyone with experience concerning this software (or any other paying service to get your iPhone unlocked)?

Comment: I wouldn't trust some website to unlock my phone. Look at your previous question, somebody updated its answer, there's now a (somehow complicated) way to unlock any iPhone (if it's jailbroken). I would advise to try that instead of paying (those kind of website really look like scam)

Comment: The website is a scam. Everyone that charges for the service and unlocks via software is a scam. All unlocks come from either the Dev Team or the Chronic Dev Team. And they are not available for all baseband revisions. When it sounds too good to be true... Here is a list that shows which versions can be successfully unlocked: http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Firmware

Comment: I guessed so :-)

Comment: @cksum I would just clarify that sometimes carrier unlocks come from other sources (like the recent [SAM-assisted SIM unlocking trick](https://twitter.com/MuscleNerd/status/193921398014615552) that was closed a few days later, or the Gevey SIM hardware unlocks that are legally sketchy but work fine), but I agree that real software unlocks are all available for free. And I think you meant a different link, since that's firmware versions, not unlocking methods...here's [a list of unlockable basebands](http://www.jailbreakqa.com/questions/32462/frequently-asked-questions#32580).

Comment: @britta, the SAM trick came out of left field, but the work was still pioneered by MuscleNerd of the Dev Team (it was later incorporated into Redsn0w). And the link is exactly the one I meant. Look to the column "Can it be unlocked?" The Gevey unlock is a hardware unlock and doesn't apply here.

Comment: @cksum I think the SAM method was based on sbingner's SAM tool, figured out by Loktar_Sun, and verified by MuscleNerd - redsn0w just backs up the activation records. I see, I missed the "Can it be unlocked?" column! It's a little bit of an odd sort of column to have on that chart since ultrasn0w unlocks depend on baseband version, not iOS version...but I see what they're doing.

Comment: @britta Yep, you are right on all counts. Don't want to steal credit from LS. You'll see that the rows do show baseband revisions along with iOS version number. The chart covers pretty much everything to do with jailbreaking/unlocking really. Even has the links to all publicly available ipfws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't trust some website to unlock my phone.

Look at your [previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43529/help-me-unlock-a-german-iphone-4-ios-5-1), somebody updated its answer, there's now a (somehow complicated) way to unlock any iPhone (if it's jailbroken). I would advise to try that instead of paying (those kind of website really look like scam).

Comment: Indeed, don't pay for software, likely any paid iPhone unlock software is merely a badged version of the same tools that people provide for free, I guarantee it will not be original software.  If it was, well, you can be sure it would itself have been "unlocked" long ago.  A quick google should provide the details for almost any but potentially the latest combinations of iOS hardware and software.  The guys who provide this stuff don't do it for the money, so don't trust anyone who does.

Answer (score 0):

they are fake. You will pay their fees and you will only get free software developed by Dev-team (Redsn0W, Ultrasn0w, and similar). They are offering as unlock solution (for 4S and baseband 04.11.08 and earlier) SAM's unlock, that as everybody knows, not works anymore.